# Calendar invite not showing up on the home tab

Tags: apex, event, calendar

I am creating an event using trigger and I'm also creating an invitee using the 
**EventRelation** object. When I go to that particular event, the invitee is shown on the list but when I go to that invitee's **Home** tab, I am not getting any notification there.

But when I create an event manually and add invitees, then the notification is present on the invitee's **Home** tab. Any particular reason?

This is my trigger to create the event and add the invitees

```
trigger Calendar on Account (after insert) {
    for(account acc : trigger.new){
        if(acc.name != NULL){
              Event e = new Event();
              e.StartDateTime = system.today();
              e.EndDateTime = system.today();
              e.Subject = 'Testing1';
              insert e;

              EventRelation er = new EventRelation(EventId = e.id,
              RelationId = '00528000001JFlo', isInvitee = True);
              insert er;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Very silly actually. Had given the start and the end date as the same hence by the time I could log in to the Invitee's org, the meeting was over. All I had to do was change the end date and it showed up